# Do you reroll a dragon's breath weapon recharge time after each breath attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dragons, breath-weapon, recharge

Dragon breath weapons have a recharge time. For example, a [very young black dragon](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dragonTrue.htm) can use its breath weapon every 1d4 rounds.

Do you re-roll the recharge time each time you use the breath weapon? Or once per (...encounter? ...day? ...dragon?)

Comment: We might consider splitting this question in two, since we seem to be getting answers that are stronger for one part than the other.

Comment: I believe that this question ought to be split in two; each of the questions have answers, but the answers are only tangentially-related. It also makes it harder for people to search for and find answers quickly and easily when multiple questions are in a single shared post.

Comment: [Related] [1d4-round cooldowns—how do they work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98580)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a rules citation for your second question, but I've always seen it played that you reroll the recharge die after every breath.

As to your first question -- from the [dragon listing](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dragonTrue.htm):

> Once a dragon breathes, it can’t breathe again until 1d4 rounds later.
>   If a dragon has more than one type of breath weapon, it still can breathe only once every 1d4 rounds.

If a dragon rolls all ones, we can replace this with:

> Once a dragon breathes, it can’t breathe again until one round later.
>   If a dragon has more than one type of breath weapon, it still can breathe only once every round.

so I think the answer is: if you roll a 1 on the 1d4, the dragon can use its breath weapon next round.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you re-roll the 1d4 each use of your breath weapon**

The key to understanding this is in [this line from the Breath Weapon special abilities entry:](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#breathWeapon) (*emphasis my own*)

> Most creatures with breath weapons are limited to a number of uses per day or by a minimum length of time that must pass **between uses**.

So that's one roll of your cool down die each and every time you use your breath weapon, unless the specific creature entry says otherwise.