# 1d4-round cooldowns—how do they work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dragons

**Or: what is the minimum amount of time between dragonbreaths?**

I've always been of the impression that, in D&D 3.5, a roll of "1" on a 1d4-round cooldown meant that the creature in question could use the ability in the next round. However, I've sometimes run into people who think it works differently, that a roll of "1" means that they can't use it in their next turn ("they must wait a whole round to use it again, *after* the turn they used it").

The relevant text of the true dragons' breath weapon is as follows:

> **Breath Weapon (Su):** Using a breath weapon is a standard action. Once a dragon breathes, it can’t breathe again until 1d4 rounds later. If a dragon has more than one type of breath weapon, it still can breathe only once every 1d4 rounds.

There's similar text in other monsters, such as the ghost's telekinesis ability:

> When a ghost uses this power, it must wait 1d4 rounds before using it again.

I am of the opinion that the definition of a *round* would imply that a "1" means the cooldown ends just before the creature's next turn, but some people I'm talking to don't think so.

> A round can be a segment of game time starting with the first character to act and ending with the last, but it usually means a span of time from one round to the same initiative count in the next round. Effects that last a certain number of rounds end just before the same initiative count that they began on.

Is there any statement **in the game's rules, including *Dragon Magazine* and the *Rules Compendium***, that specifies that these cooldowns work in a particular way? If there isn't, what about from supplemental, but not quite game rule resources, like *Rules of the Game* and *Sage Advice* articles, or the much-maligned WotC FAQ?

In the absence of that, is there a statement of the developers' RAI anywhere (i.e. a cited forum post, public chat log, or similar; *not* another rule that has been read as implying something about this one)?

And finally, if there is outright *nothing* stated about this issue, can anyone cite an English language grammar rule that would solve it?

Comment: [Heavily related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98567/4563), though I think the emphasis on RAW and/or authoritative sources differentiates the question from that one.

Comment: @KRyan Asking the same question but asking for us to cite the rules *harder* isn't a new question.

Comment: How does one go about asking to cite the rules *harder* when similar questions aren't answered unambiguously from a RAW perspective?

Comment: @godskook Downvote poorly supported answers, upvote well-supported ones. Asking the question again but adding a “for reals, please support your answer” reminder isn't the way to do it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie This isn't a duplicate question; the other dragon breath question was dealing with how the dice are rolled for its duration. This is a question about the details of rounds tracking and how meaningful cooldowns are.

Comment: @Forrestfire The other question explicitly asks in bullet #1 the same thing that this question is asking.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie While that's a fair point, the fact that the question is asking two very different, equally-important things is a problem in itself, come to think of it.

Comment: @Forrestfire That's possibly the case, and could be resolved by activity on that other question to see if it needs to be split, held, or is fine as-is. This version is much more articulate, I will own.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Per **Draconomicon** page 22, if a dragon uses its breath weapon on round 1 and then rolls a 1 on the d4 check, the dragon is next capable of breathing on round 2. This is specifically given as an example in the sidebar, spelled out unambiguously. Cheers!